# How to transform vertical z elevation coordinates in R sf

Tags: r, css-transforms, r-sf

I have some spatial data recorded by a GPS/GNSS that includes Lat/Lon and Height Above Ellipsoid (HAE, meters) altitude values, all are referenced to NAD83(2011), EPSG:6318.  I'm trying to convert the horz. to State Plane NY East (EPSG: 6537, which is successful) but how do I convert the altitude/height data to NAVD88, US-ft (EPSG: 6360)? I can apply the horizontal using `sf::st_transform(6537)` but I don't know how to apply the vertical.  I tried just stringing another `sf::st_transform(6360)` after the first transform but that didn't work. Below is a reproducible example and for reference, the output from NOAA VDatum online that shows the correct value (transformed elevation should be ~5.899 ft)

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
pt <- data.frame(Lat = 41.1578110483, Lon = -73.8716163883, Alt = -29.3619984455) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Lon", "Lat", "Alt"), crs = 6318, agr = "constant", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  st_transform(6537) %>% 
  mutate(x = st_coordinates(.)[,1],
         y = st_coordinates(.)[,2],
        z = st_coordinates(.)[,3])
pt
```

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 6 fields
Attribute-geometry relationship: 3 constant, 0 aggregate, 0 identity, 3 NA's
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: 665148.732436 ymin: 847314.319632 xmax: 665148.732436 ymax: 847314.319632
z_range:       zmin: -29.3619984455 zmax: -29.3619984455
Projected CRS: NAD83(2011) / New York East (ftUS)
            Lat            Lon            Alt                       geometry             x             y              z
1 41.1578110483 -73.8716163883 -29.3619984455 POINT Z (665148.732436 8473... 665148.732436 847314.319632 -29.3619984455
```

```
Update:
 sf_extSoftVersion()
          GEOS           GDAL         proj.4 GDAL_with_GEOS     USE_PROJ_H           PROJ 
       "3.9.0"        "3.2.1"        "7.2.1"         "true"         "true"        "7.2.1"
```

[image: NOAA VDatum Result, what I'm trying to get]

Comment: And for completeness, perhaps add your `sf_extSoftVersion()`, results above.

Comment: You might want to submit this as an issue to https://github.com/r-spatial/sf